# How to use cURL to create transactions

Tags: payments

I want to integrate my POS software with Stellar.
I'm trying cURL but I can't find how to create a transaction between 2 accounts. I found SDK for Java, Python, Ruby and C# but I can't use them in my program. I can only use cURL.
Is there any way to use cURL to create transactions?

Answer (score 1):

This is the [post transaction endpoint](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/endpoints/transactions-create.html).

To submit a transaction using `curl`, you first need to encode your transaction into XDR. You can use the [Laboratory's transaction builder](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#txbuilder?network=test) to get the next sequence number, add 1 or more operations and sign the transaction.

If you cannot use any of the SDKs you mentioned, nor can you use the laboratory to prepare the transactions, then there are other SDKs available. Notably, the [js](https://www.stellar.org/developers/js-stellar-sdk/reference/index.html) or [go](https://www.stellar.org/developers/go/reference/index.html) SDKs may help.

For example, here is a test network transaction with a single payment operation that I have signed. It can only be posted once.

> AAAAAPIt/jfTZqu43JvkLNUdfSUmv0dKUuRT8bNA3uV6ocBdAAAAZABwu74AAAANAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAIUsiN3DnxxN4J5fGl2DEo9AIh3oazstp0Xl1H+WOR8YAAAAAAAAAAElQT4AAAAAAAAAAAXqhwF0AAABAQ/buDHrZNNo4LDppkZb/G4h3tS9h9yYc766KKj7PWEb+QIRa314DJ6P+lD6Y+OtVON4APFtlGbnxkB+ku0nAAg==

With the url encoded value, I can submit the transaction with `curl`:

> curl -d
>   'tx=AAAAAPIt%2FjfTZqu43JvkLNUdfSUmv0dKUuRT8bNA3uV6ocBdAAAAZABwu74AAAANAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAIUsiN3DnxxN4J5fGl2DEo9AIh3oazstp0Xl1H%2BWOR8YAAAAAAAAAAElQT4AAAAAAAAAAAXqhwF0AAABAQ%2FbuDHrZNNo4LDppkZb%2FG4h3tS9h9yYc766KKj7PWEb%2BQIRa314DJ6P%2BlD6Y%2BOtVON4APFtlGbnxkB%2Bku0nAAg%3D%3D'
>   -X POST https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/transactions

Answer (score 1):

Bridge server has a [`POST /builder`](https://github.com/stellar/bridge-server/blob/master/readme_bridge.md#post-builder) endpoint that allows you to build arbitrary transactions.